# Struts2+Validation in liferay6

Tags: struts2, liferay

I have my view.jsp with the form :

```
<s:form action="action">
  <s:textfiled name="user"></textfield>
</s:form>
```

I created my ActionClass and ActionClass -Validation.xml in the same package.

ActionClass -Validation.xml:

```
<validators>
  <field name="user">
    <field-validator type="required">
      <message>You must enter a value.</message>
    </field-validator>
  </field>
</validators>
```

In my struts

```
<action name="action" class="com.action.ActionClass" method="execute" >
   <result name="success">/html/view/register-success.jsp</result>
   <result name="error">/html/view/register-error.jsp</result>
   <result name="input">/html/view/view.jsp</result>
</action>
```

But it doesn't work.
What it is wrong?

Comment: When your post has typos it's more difficult to help. Please consider taking the time to be precise.

Answer (score 1):

The `required` validator is for checking if the specified field is not null. You are probably want to use `requiredstring` validator which checks that a String field is non-null and has a length > 0.

Also your validation xml file name should be `ActionClass-validation.xml`, note lower case for `-validation`.

Comment: I tried to put in the ActionClass this methos public void validate() {
if (getName().length() == 0) {
addFieldError("userName", "User Name is required");
}} 
addFieldError("userName", "Invalid User");
}
But I don't see the message. It's true my method?
}

Comment: Which Struts2 them are you using? Show your JSP page.

Comment: @user2273574 Your field's name is `"user"`, not `"userName"`.